# React-Native failing to build on Android

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am trying to build a React Native application for Android, but getting some strange java access errors such as the one below:

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I'm not overly sure what is going on. I've tried upgrading my React-native version, cleaning my gradle cache and clearing node_modules and rebuilding but always getting the same problem.

Here are my versions, full stack trace and package.json dependencies:

```
➜ java -version
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
➜ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC
Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.2.3 x86_64
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@haskkor/react-native-pincode": "^1.22.5",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.7",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.5.10",
    "appcenter": "^4.0.2",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^4.0.2",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.0.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.18",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^4.3.2",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "galio-framework": "^0.7.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-floating-action-menu": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-formik": "^1.7.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "5.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.2.3",
    "react-native-woodpicker": "^0.2.8",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.0",
    "detox": "^18.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^5.0.9",
    "jest-expo": "~40.0.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
```

```
➜ ./gradlew assembleRelease
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :react-native-fs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :appcenter:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :appcenter-analytics:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-image-resizer:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: /Users/adamturner/Documents/personal/Revenite/node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/android/src/main/java/fr/bamlab/rnimageresizer/ImageResizer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :appcenter-crashes:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-image-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-community_picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: /Users/adamturner/Documents/personal/Revenite/node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/android/src/main/java/com/reactcommunity/rndatetimepicker/RNDatePickerDialogFragment.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: /Users/adamturner/Documents/personal/Revenite/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/lib/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/GestureHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings

> Task :react-native-keychain:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 14 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter-analytics:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-linear-gradient:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-resizer:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter-crashes:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

10: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

11: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

12: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

13: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

14: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-keychain:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5f4c98c5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 13s
149 actionable tasks: 148 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: What was your initial RN version?

Comment: I upgraded from 0.63

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using JAVA 16 as you mentioned above.Gradle not support this version yet.
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13629#issuecomment-680042708

**Solution:**

1. Downgrade to [JAVA 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)
2. Update `JAVA_HOME` with new `PATH`
3. Close and re-open terminal and try rebuild the project.