# I changed the version gradle and appeared this problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x5b8bd3a7) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x5b8bd3a7

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Native failing to build on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001195/react-native-failing-to-build-on-android)

Comment: degrade your java version from 16 to any older version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to Java 11 or 8 (https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu11.50.19-ca-jdk11.0.12-win_x64.msi) if you are using 16 or anything else. Also, try running `flutter clean` and building once.